# Does Varnish work with https after enabling cloudflare?

Tags: https, varnish, cloudflare

I installed Varnish 5.2 on my vps and i'm using cloudflare and https.
I added a rule to cache html pages for 1 hour then i tested the cache.
All pages were cached and expired after 1 hour and everything works fine.
It's known that Varnish doesn't work with https, so did i miss something?
I'm using Wordpress, the site is a very simple blog, only admins login to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided many details but you're probably talking about Cloudflare's service [Flexible SSL](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/). The traffic from client to CF is encrypted but the traffic from CF to your Varnish server goes over HTTP with an [X-Forwarded-Proto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) header to inform the backend server that the original request was over HTTPS and to render the website as such.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, does your answer mean that the varnish cache is working fine and i don't need to install a HTTPS front-end like Pound?

Comment: Well, the website works, doesn't it? But Flexible SSL is not the best option form security point of view so if you're concerned with that or have some spare time you may set up hitch or pound.